# Swift - Xcode: performSegue in if statement

Tags: ios, swift, segue

My intention is to only run `performSegue` if both inputs aren't empty. Turning the label's color to red works fine, but somehow it still switches to my SecondViewController. Is there a mistake in my if statement?

```
@IBAction func buttonFinishedStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (nameInput.text != "" || startKmInput.text != "") {
        name = nameInput.text!
        startKm = startKmInput.text!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender: self)
    }
    if (nameInput.text == "") {
        nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
    if (startKmInput.text == "") {
        currentKmLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

I've also tried to disable button on `viewDidLoad()` and to enable it again when both inputs are filled (haven't been able to enable it again):

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonFinished: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonFinished.isEnabled = false

}

@IBAction func buttonFinishedStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (nameInput.text != "" || startKmInput.text != "") {
        name = nameInput.text!
        startKm = startKmInput.text!
        buttonFinished.isEnabled = true
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"use" and condition istead of "or"
    if (nameInput.text != "" && startKmInput.text != "")
And where are you enabling button when both input fields are not empty

Answer (score -1):

Use `&&`...

```
if (nameInput.text != "" && startKmInput.text != "")
```